# Input hex strings as char at once

Tags: c++, hex

I have a strings like this:

```
315c4eeaa8b5f8aaf9174145bf43e1784b8fa00dc71d885a804e5ee9fa40b16349c146fb778cdf2d3aff021dfff5
```

Is there a way to read it from file at once into string object keeping in mind that every 2 chars are hexadecimal representation of byte? I.e. I need a reading with conversion from hex to char.

*UPDATE*
Guys, please read carefully what I asked.
I'm able to write conversion functions and looping along a string.
**BUT** I need read a string of hex to a string of char **at once**.
No any looping. No conversions by hands.
Something like `cin >> ...some string variable...`
Thanks.

*UPDATE2*
Imagine I have the string `"315c4eeaa8b5"`. I want to write something like `cin >> string_var` and get that string_var containing exactly the `"'0x31','0x5c','0x4e','0xea','0xa8','0xb5'"`. Please note, this last is an ordinal `std::string`. I.e. `0x31,0x5c,etc` are codes of chars.
Hope it makes thing clearer.

Comment: Your update made it even less clear. Do you want this data converted from hex-ascii *to anything* ?? It *sounds* like you want the char-pairs converted from hex-ascii to their byte-equivs, which in the sample you're providing, happen to be actual ascii chars underneath. is that correct? All without a loop, without conversions, and tucked up inside some extraction operator.?

Comment: yeah, I know exactly what they are, and no, you're not getting that with a simple extraction operator (unless you write it and perform the 2-char-to-ordinal-code conversion within said extractor). There is no silver bullet to do what you want in the std lib. And you already said you can/have write/written the conversion loop, so is there anything else?

Comment: I asked this for sure that I have to make that conversion by my own.

Comment: You do, I'm afraid. The iostreams library can make it pretty simple, or do it lower level with a couple table lookups and a 4-bit shifted or-operator. Thats up to you, but i'm afraid a canned solution from the std lib is a no-go.

Answer (score 1):

Either you code something up or you use something that already exits. If you are using C++ IO streams then I would suggest taking a look at [Boost.IOStreams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html) library and especially its [Filtering Streams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/iostreams/doc/guide/filtering_streams.html) concept. You can use the tab expanding [2.2.5.2 input_filter](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/iostreams/doc/tutorial/tab_expanding_filters.html#tab_expanding_input_filter) tutorial example as a base for your hexadecimal input filter implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use istream::opeartor>> with the std::hex manipulator to parse as hexadecimal:

```
ifstream in("...");
char buffer[3];
vector<char> chars;

while (in.read(buffer, 2))
{
    buffer[2] = '\0';

    char c;
    istringstream(buffer) >> hex >> c;
    chars.push_back(c);
}
```